# Spring Request Scoped Bean Exists In Subsequent Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a controller (Scoped: session), an autowired service (Scoped: session) and a component ("A") used by the service (Scoped: request)).

The flow at each request is expected to be like this:

```
1) Request Arrives at Controller
2) Controller has an injected service whose method is called
3) Service has an injected component A, and the method of that is called has 
   a custom PreAuthorize expression evaluating a boolean returned by the 
   method of the injected component A.
4) In successful PreAuthorize (doesn't throw access denied and it goes ahead) 
   I populate a member variable of bean A.
5) The service method is executed which uses bean A's set member variables' 
   value.
```

I get the member variable's value same each time a request is made. Basically, it's the value which was there on the first request. I change it on every PreAuthorize.. and if i debug and see what's happening, it does get changed, but when I access the bean at the service where the component is autowired, I get the old value.

So I printed the object.toString for the bean A (which is request scoped) in the service. I should get different values on each fresh request. But I'm getting the same value all the time.

What am i doing wrong? Is this standard/correct behavior for a component which is request scoped?

The following scenario works perfectly, as in i get changed values because i get updated values in the same object which is session scoped:

Controller (Scoped: session), Service( Scoped: session), Component (Scoped: session)..

**Edit**
Similarly, if all 3 are scoped request, i get different toString values for the beans.

**Edit 2**
Thinking a bit about this, is the same Component bean being returned as it is a member of the Session scoped Service/Controller? I tried Controller (session), Service (request) and Component (request), and i get the same object.toString at the Session for the autowired component. The PreAuthorize accesses the correct bean as it is not accessing the instance of the one which is autowired to the service.

**So then am i right when i say that** , it would be incorrect to have request scoped beans autowired to session scoped controllers ("smaller" scopes inside "larger" scopes)?

Comment: I think it is because Spring uses Singleton.

Comment: Please elaborate? By default, it uses singleton, but these are explicitly declared as specific scoped beans..

Comment: shouldn't you use prototype?

Comment: I don't get you? I want it request scoped.. My question is about the behavior..

Comment: Post the controller code.

Comment: There is definitely a chapter dedicated to this topic (*scoped beans inside singletons*) in Spring guide - I will try to find a link. In short - you should do this only for interface based dependencies as they will be proxied. For standard classes you would need some inheritance (CGLIB) *magic*.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection

Comment: Thank you! @PavelHoral I found this helpful at the link -->>In the preceding example, the singleton bean userManager is injected with a reference to the HTTP Session-scoped bean userPreferences. The salient point here is that the userManager bean is a singleton: it will be instantiated exactly once per container, and its dependencies (in this case only one, the userPreferences bean) are also injected only once. This means that the userManager bean will only operate on the exact same userPreferences object, that is, the one that it was originally injected with.

Comment: @ChinmayShah Spring detects the situation that it is injecting scoped bean inside a singleton bean. Instead of injecting the bean itself, it injects a special JDK proxy. This proxy is a dynamically created implementation of your interface and on every method call it asks *bean factory* to provide the scoped bean instance. So yes, the injection happens only once, but the scoped bean is dynamically obtained in every method call. This wiring mechanism allows for short lived scopes to be injected into other beans. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html